# Maintain page scrollable while fancybox is open

Tags: jquery, fancybox, scrollbar, fancybox-2

I have the Fancybox-Plugin V2 in use for a webpage. **Now I have the Problem that the background image of the body and all background-DIVs (footer-section) moves slightly to the left when the Fancybox is opened**, because the scrollbars disappear. I tried to maintain the page under the fancybox scrollable but get no succes. Has anyone a solution?

The problem only appears on pages which already have scrollbars.

These are the CSS-Settings for the moving elements:

```
#footer {width:100%;height:400px;margin-top:100px;position:absolute;text-align:center;

#footer-wrap {width:900px;text-align:center;margin:auto;}

body {background:url(images/hintergrund.jpg) top center no-repeat;}
```

Comment: what version of fancybox: v2.1 or v2.0.x??? because for v2.1 the body won't be scrollable (the `<body class="fancybox-lock"...` was introduced), however, the page shouldn't shift. Also, what browser? because it may happen in IE if is not running in standards mode.

Comment: I am using Version v2.1.1 and was running it with Firefox 15.0.1

Comment: How can I remove "fancybox-lock"? Because I think if the scrollbars don't disappear, the content won't move anymore (I gave the footer div a static width, the problem was solved then). So these "movements" are caused by the different window widths when fancybox is open and closed. With scrollbars my page-width is for example 1630px and without scrollbars 1600px. Due to the fact, that the content in the footer bar is centered with "margin:auto" it moves.

Comment: I don't know if that will solve your problem ... it might rather be a CSS design issue ;) ... anyway, remove the `fancybox-lock` adding the API option `fixed: false`

Answer (score 0):

The scroll bars should not be disappearing.  Is the page posting back or something?  You can see my fiddle below where I have added enough content to the body to create vertical scroll bars, but notice the fancyBox does not cause anything to flicker or resize.

What does your `<a>` tag look like, and how/what are you displaying with FancyBox?  IFrame, inline, etc.

http://jsfiddle.net/5Um2L/

Comment: Thanks for your time to think about my problem. I tooks two screenshot which show exactly what I mean with "move slightly to the left": [link](http://www.mediaimpulse.co/1.png) and to compare when fancybox is on [link](http://www.mediaimpulse.co/2.png)

Comment: I call the fancybox function with inline-content in one newsletter-plugin for wordpress: `function eemail_submit_ajax(url)
{
 txt_email_newsletter=document.getElementById("eemail_txt_email");
    if(txt_email_newsletter.value=="")
    {
       $.fancybox( '<h3>Bitte geben Sie eine E-Mail Adresse ein!</h3>' ); 
        txt_email_newsletter.focus();
        return false;    `